# SQL Server optimize batch save with checks

Tags: sql-server

I need to save batch of objects.

Slow performance (150 000 objects are saved in 15 minutes) is due to checks.

Check for each object - the aggregate of some fields should be unique.

So the questions are:

- will it help if I create additional indexed column with hash-value of those fields and check that column before detailed check?
- is there any other solution?

Comment: Not enough info. Are you checking row by row?

Comment: A few questions whose answers might help someone answer: (1) how many columns do you need to check? (2) Does the system need to remain highly available while this is happening?

Comment: Each object is saved individually now, i did try to organize saving of 10000 objects in transaction, the code was: if(found same data) begin raiserror return end else insert. the number of columns > 1 in most cases

Comment: what types of "objects" are you "saving"? Are these rows into a single table, rows into different tables, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are currently checking row-by-row, and that table locking during the update is not a problem, I guess you're trying to do a special case of UPSERT here (what happens if there IS already a matching row? Do you abort the process, or skip the row, or something else?)

In SQL Server 2008, a `MERGE` statement is probably what you're looking for.

In SQL Server 2005 and earlier, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to do something similar (where a key column in the joined table is null)

---

UPDATE(d twice): based on your feedback, let's assume that you are using SQL Server 2005 and want to add new rows based on a compound (multi-column) key, while avoiding (and possibly alerting on) existing/duplicate rows.

You have a table "Table1" that contains some data:

```
KeyCol1  KeyCol2   ValueCol
1        2         Test
3        2         MoreTest
4        2         TestForever
```

You have a temp table (or table variable, or loading/staging table, or something) that contains the data you want to load:

```
KeyCol1  KeyCol2  ValueCol
2        2        OKValue
5        2        AlsoOK
4        2        ProblemValue
```

You do an inner join to get any "already existing" rows (and then raise an error, or do whatever you want with that list of problem entries):

```
SELECT FinalTable.* 
INTO #ProblemRecords
FROM FinalTable 
INNER JOIN TempTable ON FinalTable.KeyCol1 = TempTable.KeyCol1
    AND FinalTable.KeyCol2 = TempTable.KeyCol2
--Could add group by here if it's possible to have more than one record per join key
```

And a left join to insert the records that **don't** have an already-matching record in the final table:

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable (KeyCol1, KeyCol2, ValueCol)
SELECT TempTable.KeyCol1, TempTable.KeyCol2, TempTable.ValueCol)
FROM TempTable
LEFT JOIN FinalTable ON FinalTable.KeyCol1 = TempTable.KeyCol1
    AND FinalTable.KeyCol2 = TempTable.KeyCol2
WHERE FinalTable.KeyCol1 Is Null
```

Some notes about this approach:

- For it to be safe, you would need to introduce large-scale locking (I have omitted transaction here for simplicity). This could be a problem for an OLTP system that needs to remain available and responsive.
- It's going to use more resources than your "slowly but surely does it" approach, while it's running.
- Somehow you need to get the data into a temporary/loading table to start with. Some sort of bulk-load process would probably make sense (see `BULK INSERT`, `bcp`, `SQLXML`, SSIS/Import-Export wizard, etc for this)

Comment: I do not understand how to use left join in this case

Comment: @blazkovicz: I'm still making assumptions here about what you mean by an "object", but I've updated my answer with an indication of how a left join would help you check all rows for a given table in one go.

Comment: still can't catch your example. Can you, please, explain what is the meaning of 'WHERE TempTable.KeyCol Is Null' and what if there are more than one keycol? let it be T1 TABLE (ID INT, Field1 varchar, Field2 varchar, Field3 varchar) that contains row (1,'1','1','whatever'), in that table we can not add row with Field1='1' AND Field2='1'

Comment: AND: in batch saving i need to add valid rows but not terminate all save

Comment: @blazkovicz: Sorry about the mess in the previous answer, the example code made no sense (it was erroring if there were any new records to insert). I have updated the example to show the use of a multicolumn key, and to insert all "new" records while collecting "existing" records somewhere else to do something else with them. hth.